# Supporting multiple plugin versions

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance

C++ Qt5

My app has a plugin architecture, and there are 6 different types of plugins. The API consists of 7 header files, each containing one abstract class: 1 base class with some common stuff, and 6 other, one for each type. Each abstract class contains some constants, pure virtual functions and slots, and signal definitions (all of the classes have the Q_OBJECT macro). The type specific classes inherit from the base class.

The plugins themselves are dynamic libraries with an "extern" factory function that returns pointers to instances of classes that are implementations of the type specific abstract classes.

All nice and well so far. However, comes the time to add new functionality to the plugins, hence to create new version(s) of the plugin API. Just in case some people ever creates 3rd party plugins, I would like to support plugins based on an old version too.

With the current setup, where the plugins include the very same header files that the app use, this means that all plugins must be recompiled every time a change is introduced. No support for older plugin versions.

If I give each plugin its own copy of the API headers, then there will be incompatibility for plugins based on an older version and the app will most likely die with some segmentation fault. Again, no support for older plugin versions.

Another thing that I thought of is each version having its own class. So I'd have like base_1, base_2, typeA_1, typeA_2, typeB_1, typeB_2, etc. etc. But Q_OBJECT doesn't support multiple inheritance, so if typeA_1 inherits from base_1, typeA_2 can not inherit from both typeA_1 and base_2. Doesn't work that way. Not to mention the hell it would create to maintain the code even if it worked...

Anybody has any good idea how to manage this situation? Or what to re-design in order to make it manageable?

Code can be viewed at launchpad.net/waver

Comment: That question might better fit at SE Software Engineering.

Comment: user0042 No such tags as SE nor Software Engineering...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone runs into a similar situation, here's what I ended up doing.

1. Put each version of the plugin API into its own directory (this means the headers for the base and the specific types abstract classes). The plugin types are still inheriting from the base, but there is no connection between the versions.
2. Plugins can include headers from whichever version they want to use.
3. Every plugin has to override a method to return compatibility level indicator.
4. Not casting objects obtained from the loaded plugin libs anymore. Instead, I use Qt's MetaObject and its Invoke method to execute plugin methods.
5. The compatibility level indicator can be used to check what methods can be executed and what signals can be connected.

Works like a charm.